# Shopware6: Plugin configuration is missing

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I'm writing my first Shopware 6 plugin and following [this howto](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/references-internals/plugins/plugin-config#entity-single-select-for-products)

But the navigation entry for Plugins will not show up. (URL: admin#/sw/settings/index) and the menu looks like this:
[image] but it should look like this: [image]

My plugin is active (checked in backend), the tables were created, so I guess it is loaded.

I copied the config.xml file from the tutorial into my plugin and validated it (just to be sure).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/platform/master/src/Core/System/SystemConfig/Schema/config.xsd">
<card>
    <title>Basic Configuration</title>
    <title lang="de-DE">Grundeinstellungen</title>

    <input-field>
        <name>email</name>
        <copyable>true</copyable>
        <label>eMail address</label>
        <label lang="de-DE">E-Mailadresse</label>
        <placeholder>you@example.com</placeholder>
        <placeholder lang="de-DE">du@beispiel.de</placeholder>
        <helpText>Please fill in your personal eMail address</helpText>
        <helpText lang="de-DE">Bitte trage deine persönliche E-Mailadresse ein</helpText>
    </input-field>

    <input-field type="single-select">
        <name>mailMethod</name>
        <options>
            <option>
                <id>smtp</id>
                <name>English smtp</name>
                <name lang="de-DE">German smtp</name>
            </option>
            <option>
                <id>pop3</id>
                <name>English pop3</name>
                <name lang="de-DE">German pop3</name>
            </option>
        </options>
        <defaultValue>smtp</defaultValue>
        <label>Mail method</label>
        <label lang="de-DE">Versand-Protokoll</label>
    </input-field>
</card>

<card>
    <title>Advanced Configuration</title>
    <title lang="de-DE">Erweiterte Einstellungen</title>

    <input-field type="password">
        <name>secret</name>
        <label>Secret token</label>
        <label lang="de-DE">Geheimschlüssel</label>
        <helpText>Your secret token for xyz...</helpText>
        <helpText lang="de-DE">Dein geheimer Schlüssel für xyz...</helpText>
    </input-field>
</card>
```

**So what is the precondition to show the Plugin navigation entry?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the problem is, I'm looking at the wrong place.

> for the settings tab, you will need an own module with an settingItem

-- Shyim

If one is using a config.xml as I do, you can configure it within the plugin configuration hidden behind the three dots.

[image]